# Issue with EDM Template making

Tags: outlook-2016

My code:

```
<td bgcolor="#0096d6">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="393" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="images/x.gif" width="30" height="1" style="display:block;"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font style="font-family:'HP Simplified';font-size:28px;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;">New Platforms to Elevate ProTrain to the next level in February</font>
      </td>
<!--space problem-->
      <td>
        <img src="images/x.gif" width="30" height="1" style="display:block;"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

How can anybody help to solve this? Here 1 px space is coming after the end of the text `<td>` in outlook 2016 only.

Comment: Ehm, the tds don't have borders, so do you mean there's a 1px space between the word "2016" and the image?

Comment: not word 2016.sapce came between TD s in outlook 2016 version